# Desktop notifier with no visible form to user

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to make a application that runs with no form interaction with user and only specific person can run a form and change config setting. The application is desktop reminder which runs every 4 months and shows up a notification.

I don't have any idea how to start it. Please guide me with some good suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an application that needs to notify the user once every 4 months, its a bit overhead to have it running all the time.

Use the Task Scheduler in Windows, to schedule this command to run (once per day, or every week) check if the condition is met. If not silently exit.

Comment: can you explain it further more?

Comment: Using the Task Scheduler, you can schedule an application to become active on a regular base. When started, let the application check if it needs to notify the user. I would not like an application "eating" cpu-cycles and memory on my system if it is only activated once every 4 months.

Comment: sorry i want to show my own notification like google talk chat alert

Comment: You are still running your own application, so its your notification.

Comment: thanks i got the idea is there any way to set task programmatically in c# code

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively create a windows Service and then configure it to allow it interact with the desktop through the Services administration console.

However, for security reasons in W2008 Server (and I assume that more or less it will be the same with W7 or even Vista, you'll have to try it) this behaves differently, and services that interact with the desktop are not allowed. Actually, I remember that when I created and showed a Window I got a notification and when clicking on it the desktop switched to another one with my window. Still, no issue with XP, I've done it.